# How to use Tag helpers inside Areas in Dot net core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I already add tag helper reference to project json .It work fine in default view folder.But when I can't use them inside Folder in  AREA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `_ViewImports.cshtml` file in each `Views` folder within `Areas` folders and add this import statement.

```
@addTagHelper "*,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

I added image for reference, how to place this file.

[image]